# Spring get actual scheme from reverse proxy

Tags: spring, redirect, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I have a Spring Boot Web application running on Widlfly server. I implemented Facebook OAuth login by generate a button "Login With Facebook" linked to Facebook login endpoint.

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=****&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://example.com/login/facebook
```

I generate the value of `redirect_uri` using following java code.

```
public static String getFacebookRedirectUrl() {
    RequestAttributes attrs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    if (attrs instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) attrs).getRequest();
        return request.getScheme() + "://"
                + request.getServerName() + ":"
                + request.getServerPort()
                + request.getContextPath()
                + "/login/facebook";
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot determine facebook oauth redirect url");
    }
}
```

My website is deployed internally to `http://my-ip-address:8080` and have a reversed proxy (nginx) forwarding requests from `https://example.com` to `http://my-ip-address:8080`.

The problem is the `redirect-uri` is always generated as `http://example.com/login/facebook` instead of `https://example.com/login/facebook` (not `https`).

Please help suggest how make `request.getScheme()` returns `https` correctly when the user access the website via `https`. Following is the reverse proxy configuration `/etc/nginx/sites-enalbed/mysite.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/cert.key;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-ip-address:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.getScheme()` will always be http because you are proxying via http, but you are passing the request scheme in a header, so use that.

Change `return request.getScheme() + "://"` to `return request.getHeader('X-Forwarded-Proto') + "://"`

Not sure how java interprets headers, so `X-Forwarded-Proto` might become `X_Forwarded_Proto` or `xForwardedProto` or something else, but you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot rely on the header as it is specific to reverse proxy engine. I use Nginx In my test environment but I have no control for the production and other test environment.

Comment: Better use `ForwardedHeaderFilter` as Bean. This will translate X-Forwarded-* into `req.geteSchema()`- https://tomgregory.com/spring-boot-behind-load-balancer-using-x-forwarded-headers/